# В чем причина ошибки BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, исключения

код **spring-db-context.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.training.dataaccess" />

    <!-- Enable Annotation based Declarative Transaction Management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"
        transaction-manager="transactionManager" />


  <!-- Creating TransactionManager Bean, since JDBC we are creating of type 
        DataSourceTransactionManager -->
   <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="com.training.dataaccess.util.SchemaNameAwareBasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
        <property name="schema" value="${db.schema}" />
    </bean>

    <context:property-placeholder
        ignore-unresolvable="true" location="classpath:app.properties" />

</beans>
```

**Код интерфейса:**

```
package com.training.services;

import com.training.dataaccess.model.Group;
import com.training.dataaccess.model.User;

public interface UserService {

    void insertOrUpdate(User user);

    void registerUser(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String login, String pass);

    void setAdminTrue(User user);

    User get(Long id);

    void userAdd2Group(User user, Group group);
}
```

**код класса**

```
package com.training.services.impl;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.training.dataaccess.dao.UserDao;
import com.training.dataaccess.model.Group;
import com.training.dataaccess.model.User;
import com.training.services.UserService;

@Component
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {

    }

    @Override
    public void insertOrUpdate(User user) {
        if (user.getId() == null) {
            userDao.insert(user);
        } else {
            userDao.update(user);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerUser(String firstName, String lastName, String email,String login, String password) {

        User user = new User();


        user.setLogin(login);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setFirstName(firstName);
        user.setLastName(lastName);
        user.setCreationDate(new Date());
        user.setCertificateId(user.getId());
        user.setGroupId(null);
        userDao.insert(user);

        // send email
    }

    @Override
    public User get(Long id) {
        return userDao.getById(id);
    }
    @Override
    public void userAdd2Group(User user, Group group){
        userDao.updateGroupId(user, group);
    }
    @Override
    public void setAdminTrue(User user) {
        userDao.setAdmin(user);

    }
}
```

Код теста:

```
package com.training.services;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

import com.training.dataaccess.model.User;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:spring-db-context.xml")
public class UserServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @Test
    public void UserService() {

        String firstName = RandomStringUtils.random(255);
        String lastName = RandomStringUtils.random(255);
        String email = RandomStringUtils.random(255);
        String login = RandomStringUtils.random(255);
        String password = RandomStringUtils.random(255);

        service.registerUser(firstName, lastName, email, login, password);
        service.registerUser(firstName, lastName, email, login, password);

        User registeredUser = service.get(1l);
        User registeredUser2 = service.get(2l);


        Assert.assertEquals(registeredUser,registeredUser2);

    }

}
```

**вот что в итоге :**

```
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
    18:18:06.554 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@7e7be63f] to prepare test instance [com.training.services.UserServiceTest@6cd28fa7]
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.training.services.UserServiceTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.training.services.UserService com.training.services.UserServiceTest.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.training.services.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:384) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:110) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:75) ~[spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:319) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:212) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:232) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:175) [spring-test-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:?]
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:?]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.training.services.UserService com.training.services.UserServiceTest.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.training.services.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 26 more
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.training.services.UserService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1103) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:963) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-4.0.3.RELEASE.jar:4.0.3.RELEASE]
        ... 26 more
```

Очень прошу тынуть где и что неправильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в XML:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.training.dataaccess" />
```

А в классе:

```
package com.training.services.impl;
```

Соответственно спринг не там ищет и ничего не находит